# How to setup access dependency on a block content created programatically

Tags: 8, blocks, layout-builder

In Drupal 8, I am creating block instances (BlockContent) for node layouts programatically and setting them all as non-reusable. That causes a following access error: "Non-reusable blocks must set an access dependency".

How do I set access dependency on an existing block instance (or during it's creation)? Was never in a position to have to manipulate access from such angle and I can't find a good example for this.

Answer (score 0):

The [BlockContent](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21Entity%21BlockContent.php/class/BlockContent/9.3.x) class uses the [RefinableDependentAccessTrait](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21Access%21RefinableDependentAccessTrait.php/trait/RefinableDependentAccessTrait/9.3.x) which has 2 methods that can be used to add/set access dependencies:

- [RefinableDependentAccessTrait::addAccessDependency](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21Access%21RefinableDependentAccessTrait.php/function/RefinableDependentAccessTrait%3A%3AaddAccessDependency/9.3.x)
  Adds an access dependency into the existing access dependency.
- [RefinableDependentAccessTrait::setAccessDependency](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block_content%21src%21Access%21RefinableDependentAccessTrait.php/function/RefinableDependentAccessTrait%3A%3AsetAccessDependency/9.3.x)
  Sets the access dependency. If an access dependency is already set this will replace the existing dependency.